# how can i count how many people in table a?

Tags: mysql

how can i count how many people in table a?

there 4 people exists in the below table , how can i get "4" in mysql?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `a`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a`;
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `date` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of a
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('1', 'jimmy', '2014-02-11 09:24:42');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('7', 'khon', '2014-02-19 09:24:50');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('3', 'jimmy', '2014-01-11 09:25:03');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('4', 'kelvin', '2013-12-11 09:25:09');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('5', 'ricky', '2014-02-12 09:25:14');
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use count on distinct name of the persons.

```
select count(distinct name) from a mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(distinct(name)) as count from a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNT` LIke

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unclear in your question. What is it that you want to count?, number of distinct persons or the total number of people in the table?

```
SELECT COUNT(name) from a;
```

You may use DISTINCT clause with it or you can also perform GROUP BY to get the count of users by grouping them.